# get value of an object in another class

Tags: qt

How to get value of an object in another class? Such as I have 2 classes (class WidgetA and class WidgetB) both those classes are created by class Widget, like this:

```
//widget.h

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>

class widgetA;
class widgetB;

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QComboBox* comboBox;
    QStackedWidget* stackWidget;
    widgetA *wa;
    widgetB *wb;
};

class widgetA : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    widgetA(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    QString mystr;
    QLineEdit* lineEdit;
};

class widgetB : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    widgetB(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QLabel* label;
};
```

And this is file widget.cpp:

```
#include "widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
    comboBox->addItem(tr("Widget A"));
    comboBox->addItem(tr("Widget B"));

    wa = new widgetA(this);
    wb = new widgetB(this);

    stackWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
    stackWidget->addWidget(wa);
    stackWidget->addWidget(wb);
    stackWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

    connect(comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), stackWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(comboBox);
    layout->addWidget(stackWidget);

    setLayout(layout);
}

widgetA::widgetA(QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(lineEdit);
    lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);

    setLayout(lay);
}


widgetB::widgetB(QWidget *parent):
    QWidget(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel("Hello QT");
    QHBoxLayout* lay = new QHBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(lay);
}
```

How to I get text of QLabel `label` in WidgetB class into QString `mystr` in WidgetA class?

Comment: you want to get it on particular event?

Comment: @Kunal: I want to get it went my app is launched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way in terms of proper decoupling and separation of concerns is to add a getter forwarding label->text():

```
QString widgetB::text() const //or more specific name depending on the context
{
    return label->text();
}
```

If you need notification when the value changes, add a signal:

```
class widgetB : public QWidget {
...
Q_SIGNALS:
    void textChanged(const QString& text);
...
};
```

and emit it whenever you update the label.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to get the value of QLabel went my app is launched. Can I put the connect in a load event went app is launched? and what event can do that?

Comment: you can do that in Widget class's constructor, using above mentioned API